# What information is sent to a wireless network using WPA/WPA2 PSK when a wireless device connects?

Tags: wireless-router, lan, connection, internet-connection

For instance, if my phone or computer connects to a wireless network using WPA/WPA2 PSK, what information about itself does it send to that network, and how can a network determine if the device is a handheld or laptop/desktop/other?

I know that a device sends the hostname and the MAC address, but is there anything else?

Comment: @Ramhound My school somehow did... Edit: they are blocking (most) phones from connecting

Comment: @Ramhound It's stuck on the obtaining an IP address phase (im on Android). My phone used to connect, and now it doesn't.

Comment: @Ramhound Was planning on sending them an email tonight.

Comment: @Ramhound What is sent for the different types of encryption then?

Comment: @Ramhound In that case, what is sent with WPA2?

Comment: It sounds like your school is using a RADIUS server, which can allow or deny access to the network, based on your MAC address.

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, thanks for that info. What is sent with WPA/WPA2 PSK? Edit: I'm not sure on what type of encryption my school uses...

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot find the encryption type, but I edited my question.

Comment: Contact the IT Administrator and find out if they are using a RADIUS server or not.